# customization of the camera overlay

Tags: iphone

My first question for customization is at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147458/add-a-uibarbutton-for-zbarreaderviewcontroller/10147745#comment13026724_10147745) and with help from [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251513/mat). I can customize it. Now I would like to customize the overlay by loading and view from a nib file...
What I am to do is

> Create another UIViewController called myCustomVIew with its xib
>
> Add a toolbar on top and some buttons onto it
>
> Set controller.cameraOverlay = aView.view

Please take a look at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK2OF.png), so that you can picture what I am doing so far
[image]

However when I run my app, the view is shown at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQdWh.png).[image]

I know I have just screwed up somewhere, please advice me about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a clearColor on the view, otherwise you can't see the camera layer.

Comment: there we go... Just set it to clearColor and it worked . You save me a day.. Thanks Mat