# back button does not work,customization of the camera overlay

Tags: iphone

After adding  a top navigation bar for customization of the camera overlay at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147745/251513). Now I am trying to go back to the previous screen by adding an action to the back button. What I am doing is

> -(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
>
> ```
> NSLog(@"back button is clicked");
>
> [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
> ```
>
> }

However, the transition is no executed even though the console shows

> back button is clicked

I also try

> [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]

However,it does not work either
Have you encountered this issue before, please advice me about it. Thanks

PS : I dont wanna use the cancel button built-in controls (when showsZBarControls=YES )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the controller you are sending this message to is a modal view controller. You have to send

```
dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
```

to the actual modal view controller.  So it will look like this

```
[self.someModalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or you could add this code to your modal view controller

```
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"back button is clicked");

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

This code implies that you have knowledge of your modal view controller in the previous view.  You might look into adding these view controllers into a UINavigationController so all this would be taken care of.

Comment: sorry i dont get it..what you commented is exactly what I have done and it is not working...

Comment: hey sorry, I have just re-read your comment again and found out that I was sending **dismisModelViewControllerAnimated** to a non-modal view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your ZBarViewController as class var, then you can call:

```
[self.yourZbarReder dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

i assume you are using zbarreader or something like that, you have to make that instance dismiss the thing, read the documentation for it, they clearly say that the zbar picker should be the one dismissing itself, so get the zbarimagepicker instance to dismiss it.